# Is it necessary to suspend a process before terminating it?

Tags: windows-7, windows, process, process-explorer

What happens when a process in Windows is suspended by Process Explorer or similar software (e.g., Process Hacker)? I've read somewhere on the web that the Sysinternals authors recommend suspending the process first before terminating it.

Is there any difference if I terminate the process directly instead?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it's not necessary. However, if you have malware on your system that uses multiple processes that act as watchdogs for each other, then you would suspend them all first before terminating any of them.

Comment: +1 In case of Malware Cleaning, suspending the protection helps shut down the protected process.

Answer (score 7):

In Process Explorer, the process is suspended using the `NtSuspendProcess` syscall. See [this page](http://j00ru.vexillium.org/?p=118) for several other possible methods.

There is no difference whether a process is suspended or running at time of termination – in both cases, the [`TerminateProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686714(v=vs.85).aspx) Win32 API is used, giving no chance for cleanup.