# File delete - access is denied even with /F

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-10, malware-removal

I'm trying to delete an executable, but it fails with the error *Access is denied* even adding `/F` to force it as `del /F system.exe`. I'm using an elevated Command Prompt.

Attempting to delete the file through Windows Explorer yields the following:

[image: error message]

I went into the Security properties of the executable. Highlighted are the odd permission entries which may be stopping me from deleting this file:

[image: advanced security settings]

Originally, it did not let me delete the entries; the option was greyed out. I performed `takeown /F C:\ProgramData\994146\system.exe`, deleted the entries, added ones which gave me full permissions, and closed the dialogue box. The error persisted. When I reopened the Advanced Security Settings, the entries were back.

The parent folder of system.exe, 994146, is completely invisible in ProgramData. I have "show hidden files" on ProgramData. I had to manually type the path in Windows Explorer's address bar. I am also not sure how to edit the properties of 994146 since I can not select it in the file hierarchy.

Comment: you say "even" with /F it's not like /F is some powerful thing. What about something  many find effective, like unlocker?(google unlocker) or any of the normal techniques one uses when they can't delete a file in windows, like using process explorer to see if any process is locking the file.. You know - techniques that people tend to find work.. Techniques that are listed whenever anybody asks how to delete a file that windows won't let you delete

Comment: And why do you write "batch delete" in the title, and then you write "I'm trying to delete an executable,"  .   Batch is like a bat file, rather than command line. This is one command, not a batch file

Comment: If you have malware like this, you really ought to backup your data and wipe the machine.

Comment: I am curious if you "even" checked if system.exe is in task manager?  (given that it showed in process explorer)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, viruses or rootkits from my PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-viruses-or-rootkits-from-my-pc)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

In my case, the solution to this particular problem was to run Kaspersky's [TDSSKiller](https://support.kaspersky.com/5350); it may have been a trojan. Unfortunately, I'm not sure specifically what TDSSKiller did to remove the affected file.

Comment: It's one piece of anti malware software and no one piece of anti malware software has any magic power to eliminate absolute any trojan.   I'm not necessarily suggesting using more than one, maybe one should, maybe not, but i'm just saying your claim is either extravagent or meaningless. "should completely eliminate" (what does 'should' mean. So when you run an anti malware program and it doesn't do it you scratch you head and say it should have? ) And you give no argument to support your claim either.

Answer (score 10):

### Put bad processes on ice:

1. Download and run [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) (from Microsoft) as Admin
2. In the **Options** > **VirusTotal.com** menu enable **Check VirusTotal.com** and accept the license agreement
3. A new column will appear titled *VirusTotal* with a number like `0/57`. The first number indicates how many virus scanners think the process is infected.  The second number indicates how many scanned the file.  `0/57` would indicate a clean process while `19/57` would indicate 19 scanners think the process is bad.
4. For any processes flagged as infected, right-click and **Suspend** (do not kill)
5. Once all suspicious processes have been suspended, kill them one at a time
6. If any new infected processes re-appear, suspend them and don't kill them
7. Change the file permissions on your unwanted executable to regain Full Control, then delete it
8. Once you've deleted the file, you need to immediately move into [scanning your computer for malware](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-viruses-or-rootkits-from-my-pc)

---

### If this doesn't work, then break out the fire:

1. Download and run [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) (also from Microsoft) and run as Admin
2. On the **Filter** menu click **Filter...**
3. Create a filter condition to match your file as follows:
   [image]
4. Click **Add** then **OK**
5. Change the permissions on your file
6. Review Process Monitor's output.  You'll see that `explorer.exe` accesses the file (that's you, changing the permissions).  Look for **any other** processes that touches the file...most likely the last process to do so.  This is most likely going to be your malicious process.
7. Use Process Explorer to suspend that process (the `PID` value shown by Process Monitor is also shown by Process Explorer)
8. Try changing the permissions/deleting the file again

Comment: All processes report 0/56 or 0/57. I believe the process only begins at startup. However, this does not allow me to regain Full Control over the folder/file.

Comment: Ah, I found it within seconds. My bad. Anyway, I already know the only remnant of the trojan remaining. I just can't delete the file. I've already deleted the registry entry that caused it to launch with explorer on startup.

Comment: I reread the first guide to successfully stop it inverting against my will. It detected malicious files now. However, Explorer will not delete it because it's open. If I kill the process, it reopens somehow. Trying the second guide now.

Comment: _How_ do you know it's the only remnant? What makes you so sure there's not a rootkit that you can't even see?

Comment: system.exe is what's changing the security back, but when I kill it, it respawns.

Comment: [MANY respawns](http://i.imgur.com/njV4dTy.png) which are all suspended

Comment: The second solution is bringing up a bunch of copies of system.exe with the same PID

Comment: It also says "showing 19,000 of 7,400,000 events" and counting. Is that bad?

Comment: When I kill system.exe after expanding it, csrss and svchost go off.

Comment: @Gnomechild The large number of events in Process Monitor is normal. The fact **csrss.exe** is involved means you have a serious infection. You need to move into full scale malware removal efforts. You have more going on than you originally thought.

Comment: Since I don't use Windows NT, csrss.exe is actually NOT fundamental to my system, right? I can destroy it entirely?

Comment: Oh, I have the textbook example of having two csrss processes open.

Comment: @Gnomechild **That's not correct**. This process is critical to Windows operation. Trust me, if something running inside (i.e. "injected") in this process is preventing you from deleting a bad file, you've got a serious infection. Act accordingly.

Comment: Although at this point it's probably best to ditch all of my personal files and reformat, I've heard tools such as SDFix can remove this, but all the links are dead. What should I do?

Comment: I am curious.. I suppose that ythe reason you suspend them first, is the reason stated here http://superuser.com/questions/325603/is-it-necessary-to-suspend-a-process-before-terminating-it  which is that they may act as watchdogs on each other.. Considering though that if you suspended them one by one they could still act as watchdogs for each other, and that you  can I suppose get around that by suspending them all at the same time.. How would that be any better than killing them all at the same time?

Comment: @barlop You're correct that this is an anti-watchdog technique. I've not enjoyed the same success by *killing* the processes simultaneously. It only takes a millisecond for a watchdog process to see its buddy dead and respawn it. Compared to the suspend-and-kill approach, it's tough to kill a number of process that fast. I've yet to have a process take action against *suspending* its buddies, but I suppose that day is coming.

Answer (score 7):

Just run these commands:

```
takeown /F * /R /D Y
icacls . /T /C /grant administrators:F System:F everyone:F
del * /s /q
```

Comment: That's awesome, very very thanks

Comment: Good answer, but note that this acts on _all_ of the _current directory_, unlike the OP's question which was about a _specific file_.

Comment: ERROR: Invalid argument/option - '*'.
Type "TAKEOWN /?" for usage.

Comment: `takeown /F * /R /D  Y` I think

Answer (score 3):

## To Delete a specific file:

When `del /f <FILE>` producing an Access Denied error, you need to firstly take owner and grant access using `takeown` and `icacls` in the command line utilities.

---

### Take owner:

```
takeown.exe /F <FILE-PATH>
```

*Note: Make sure to change `<FILE-PATH>` to the full name of the desired file.*

**Output example:**

> SUCCESS: The file (or folder): "[FILE-PATH]" now owned by user "PC-NAME\USER-NAME".

### Grant user access right:

```
icacls.exe <FILE-PATH> /grant PC-NAME\USER-NAME:F
```

*Note: Make sure to change `<FILE-PATH>` and `PC-NAME\USER-NAME` accordingly (don't miss the `:F`).*

**Output example:**

> processed file: [FILE-NAME]
> Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files

### Delete the file:

```
del /f <FILE-PATH>
```

Comment: The question states that that had already been tried.

Comment: What if `takeown.exe /f` gives `ERROR: Access is denied.`?

Answer (score 1):

This is my "chown.bat" (unix folks will laugh at me using that name). I've cobbled it together from various solutions... Each time one doesn't work, I add more stuff. The SetACL stuff I only discovered in 2014 or 2015. This has never failed me:

```
    for /r %fn in (*.*)  SetACL -on "%fn" -ot file -actn clear -clr dacl,sacl
    takeown /F * /R /D  Y
    icacls   *.* /T /C /grant YOURUSERACCOUNTNAMEHERE:(D,WDAC)
    icacls    .  /T /C /grant administrators:F System:F everyone:F
```

SetACL is a 3rd party utility that needs to be in your path.

Comment: Comment submitted as an edit: [This solution worked, thank you! However, I had to change your FOR line in 2 ways. At least on Windows 10, the %variable seems to have to be a single letter. So your "%fn" became just "%f" if that line is run at the command line. (And note that if you put those lines in a batch file, that variable has to have double % signs, as in "%%f", which is what I have above.) Finally, I needed to add "DO" before the "SetACL". See above. And many thanks again for finally getting me to where I could just delete an executable]

Comment: Thanks! I use TakeCommand (TCC.EXE) as a command-line, so I may have minor variances in my implementations :)   It's nice to know someone went through it with a fine-tooth comb to make it more compatible to more common command-lines. I might just change my local BAT file to reflect your edits just for giggles :)

Comment: Also, for TakeCommand, instead of YOURUSERACCOUNTNAMEHERE, one can get away with %_winuser% -- not sure if that works elsewhere.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work for me.

Comment: "This has never failed me" - well, try it on any file in "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Scans\History\Service\DetectionHistory\00", and you may see "SetACL error message: The call to SetNamedSecurityInfo () failed. Operating system error message: Access is denied."